# pixel by pixel reconstruct image in python

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a script that lists all the pixel data in hex from an image. Does PIL or similar library have an easy way to reconstruct the image from the output text? This is what I use to get the data

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image

def rgb2hex(r, g, b):
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g, b)

img = Image.open('apple_raw.png')

if img.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA') or (img.mode == 'P' and 'transparency' in img.info):   
    pixels = img.convert('RGBA').load()
    width, height = img.size

    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            r, g, b, a = pixels[x, y]
            print '%s,%s,%s' % (x, y, rgb2hex(r, g, b))
```

output (snip)

```
0,0,#ffffff
0,1,#ffffff
0,2,#ffffff
0,3,#ffffff
0,4,#ffffff
...
...
304,308,#ffffff
304,309,#ffffff
304,310,#ffffff
304,311,#ffffff
304,312,#ffffff
304,313,#ffffff
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ftkL.jpg image I'm using for testing

Comment: image size is 305x314 would I have to define that when writing the image? any hints in the right direction where to look, documentation etc would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to image processing

Comment: You can use similar for-loop code to rebuild your image from your text file.  However, this is about the most inefficient way of saving and loading an image you could choose.  Why aren't you saving the image in some proper image format instead?

Comment: @SvenMarnach What would be more efficient? putting the pixels in a flat array? I need all the pixel data. I know its not efficient, but it does what I need it to do. I have some text files with this sort of data and I'm trying to rebuild the images from it.

Comment: So you are getting images in this format from an external source?  Given that you showed code to store images in this format, I was assuming you are generating the files yourself.  If you control the code storing the images, you should just use some image format, like PNG.  It will use 20 times less storage, and will load several hundred times faster.  If you don't control the source of the image, then you have to do what's in the answer below, or something similar.

Comment: @SvenMarnach okay, thanks. I am generating them myself. I am looking for something similar to below though. I will see if that works for me. In the future I will use a different format.

Comment: You can save an image as a PNG using `img.save("img.png")` and load it again using `img = Image.load("img.png")`, which is much easier and faster than what you are doing.  This is what I recommend you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my code to extract the rgb instead of hex (255,255,255), I had a hard time splitting the x,y and the rgb tuples from one file, So I split the file into two files, one for RGB and one for Coordinates. Then I used numpy and scipy to map the pixels. Here is the code in case it will help someone else trying to do something similar. It may not be the ideal way to accomplish this but I got the desired results.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import scipy.misc as sc

img = np.zeros((305,314,3), dtype=np.uint8) 

with open ('coordinates') as coord, open('rgbvalues') as rgb:
    for coord,rgb in itertools.izip(coord,rgb):
        rgb = map(int, rgb.split(','))
        r = rgb

        coord = map(int, coord.split(','))
        c = coord
        img[c[0],c[1]] = [r[0],r[1],r[2]]
    img = sc.toimage(img)
    img.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new image and set that image's pixel data:

```
width, height = (305, 314)

new_image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
data = new_image.load()

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        data[(x, y)] = (r, g, b)

new_image.save('foo.png', 'png')  # or another format
```

Take a look at [`Image.frombytes`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes) and [`Image.fromstring`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromstring), as well.

Comment: This almost works, I mean it does create the image foo.png if I add the lines to my script. The `Image.frombytes` takes data from the buffer, I am trying to recreate the image from the text file (output above) not from memory.